# iphone 4 video upload compression

Tags: iphone, video, compression

i have an app that uploads some video through an http POST command to a server. on the iPhone 4 (and possibly the 3GS) when the user uploads a 34 second video a little thing pops up at the bottom of the screen and says that the video is being compressed. probably for faster upload. problem being is that the server guy says he can't uncompress the videos on the server end. this is causing problems when someone tries to view the videos. on the iphone 4 they look compressed when viewed and on my 2nd gen iTouch the videos don't play at all.

so the question is can i turn off the compression on my end? or can i suggest something to the server guy to uncompress them on his end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out if you FTP the files to the server instead of using HTTP POST the video files arrive just fine without that ugly compression people have been complaining about.

Comment: I don't think this is true.  The file is compressed before you're given a handle to it on the device, how you upload it shouldn't matter .  You can confirm this by saving the resulting file to your 'library' and then download both directly to your computer.  The original should be a larger file size.

Comment: i thought the same thinking till i saw an FTP app upload a video from an iPhone 4 with no issues. import a video then download the app's Application Data. look in the tmp folder. yes the video is compressed and smaller than the original file but if you play it the video quality is fairly good. not as good as the original but not horribly pixelated like you get when you send it over HTTP.